# In C#, how can I get the top items that are properties of a list?

Tags: c#, collections, group-by

I have a project object which has a list of sponsors (which is an array of Person objects) as seen below

```
var projectA = GetProject();
IEnumerable<Person> sponsors = projectA.Sponsors;
```

I now have list of these projects objects

```
List<Project> projects = GetProjects();
```

and I am trying to get the "top sponsors" for all projects

If a project had a single sponsor, I would do something like this:

```
var topSponsors = projects.GroupBy(r->r.Sponsor).OrderByDescending(g->g.Count)
```

but in my case a project has multiple sponsors so I am looking for the right syntaxt that shows the top sponsors across this list of projects?

As an example, lets say

Project 1 ==> Sponsors (Tim, Joe)
Project 2 ==> Sponsors (Tim)
Project 3 ==> Sponsors (Bill)
Project 4 ==> Sponsors (Tim, Joe)

I would want to order by:

Tim (3 projects)
Joe (2 projects)
Bill (1 projects)

Comment: How you define "top sponsors"? Could you please provide an example of input and desired output?

Comment: Is that a typo: "I have a person object"? I assume you mean "I have a project object". Reaplace `var` with the real type.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - yes, i fixed the typo

Comment: @Christos - I have added some example data to clarify my request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the top n persons of all persons in the projects?

```
var top10Persons = projects
    .SelectMany(p=> p.Sponsors)
    .GroupBy(p => p)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Take(10)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

This presumes that `Person` overrides `Equals` + `GetHashCode`. You could also provide a custom `IEqualityComparer<Peerson>` for `GroupBy.`If you also want the `Count` of each person you could select an anonymos type:

```
    .....
    .Take(10)
    .Select(g => new { Count = g.Count(), Person = g.First() });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var bestSponsors = projects.SelectMany(p => p.Sponsors)
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.ToList().Count)
    .Select(p => new
           {
               Name = p.Key,
               SponsoredProjectCount = p.ToList().Count
           })
    .ToList();
```

I am assuming you have a person class like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```